# pod install ERROR: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)

Tags: cocoapods, podfile, yarn-v2

I already installed cocoapods using `brew install cocoapods` and it's 1.12.1, I also already have `openssl` but when I run pod install I always get this error:

`[!] Couldn't determine repo type for URL:` https://cdn.cocoapods.org/`: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 peeraddr=104.26.0.240:443 state=error: certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

I think it might related to certification trust or anything related but it still not working

I already update the cocoapods, make sure the date and time is correct and same as the actual time, update RubyGems Ceritificates, update OpenSSL, and make sure there is no firewall on.

I want to change the the certificate to be "Always Trust" but I'm not sure which ceriticate that I should choose. Anyway, I'm using Apple M1 (idk is it related or not but yeah just to make sure)"

I will really appreciate your help so that I can run my project, please comment if you need any further info

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. This worked for me.
Enter this line in the Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

Create the following directory structure:

`~/.cocoapods/repos`

Then clone the cocoa pods in this directory.

```
cd ~/.cocoapods/repos
git clone "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs" master --depth 1
```

Now run the pod install again. The cert error should be gone. This solution was mentioned in the [apple developer forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/126514)

Comment: this should be the answer. you save my life ^^